# Weekly distance buildup for 100k ultra

Tags: running, ultramarathons

I'm going to run a 100k next July. I'm trying to plan my weekly mileage, and I'm wondering what periodisation I should do.

I'm currently thinking of going for a monthly basis. Increase in week 1 & 2, then maintain the higher mileage in week 3, then lower mileage to recover. For example:

Week-1: 74
Week 1: 86
Week 2: 98
Week 3: 98
Week 4: 80

Since I have plenty of time, I don't really need to increase too fast. Repeating the mileage in the 3rd week allows me to evaluate if I've accumulated fatigue or not. Then I have an easier week to recover. Then in the next serie I will to a bit more than 100, etc.

- Any argument for a shorter period? For example every other week?
- Any argument for a longer period? Why would it make sense to increase continuously for longer?

Details: I've run a 100k before (few years ago). I have a good volume basis. The overall idea is to bring my weekly distance to 100k on a regular basis, but it's fine if the pullback week goes below that, or if for whatever reason I do less for 2-3 weeks. I also have to manage the increase of my long runs in parallel to that. Which is also a reason why I though of a long cycle. I know about "the 10% rule". I think it's fine with a good base volume to do more than that.

Comment: Have you reach your goals? Could you share your experiences with the community? Self answering questions is not only allowed, it's also encouraged :)